# USB keyboard not working after building the mainline Linux kernel on a generic Allwinner A23 Chinese tablet

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, cross-compilation, u-boot, usb-otg

For quite a while I've been trying to install a Debian distribution on my useless cheap tablet PC. After reading the details of building Linux kernel on ARM architecture [Manual Build Howto](http://linux-sunxi.org/Manual_build_howto) I've found out that the mainline Linux has support for Allwinner A23 SoC [Mainline Kernel Howto](http://linux-sunxi.org/Mainline_Kernel_Howto). Besides that, building the kernel is possible with mainline U-Boot [Mainline U-Boot Howto](http://linux-sunxi.org/Mainline_U-boot) by using the bootloader binaries for respective architecture and a specific boot.scr script.

After performing the necessary configurations I've obtained a bootable SD card with the following contents:

**Partition 1:**

*boot.scr* - script used to load the kernel image and device tree blob into memory

*zImage* - mainline Linux kernel image

*[device_tree].dtb* - device tree blob specific for my tablet

**Partition 2:**

*rootfs* - root file system for Debian Stretch

Having a working USB keyboard is essential for my tablet, because it has only one micro USB OTG port, which I intend to use for keyboard/mouse/charging, thus when compiling the kernel, configurations specific for USB and full HID support were used:

```
CONFIG_INPUT_MOUSE=y
CONFIG_INPUT_TOUCHSCREEN=y
CONFIG_INPUT_KEYBOARD=y
CONFIG_HID_SUPPORT=y
CONFIG_HID=y
CONFIG_USB_OTG=y
CONFIG_USB_HID=y
CONFIG_USB=y
CONFIG_USB_MOUSE=y
CONFIG_USB_OTG_UTILS=y
```

and many more configs which I'm not sure about, but included just in case.

After multiple tries with various kernel configurations I keep obtaining the same result, where the USB keyboard works perfectly in U-Boot when connected via either OTG cable or USB hub, but fails to work when kernel boots -- I can't get past the tty1 prompt asking to enter my credentials, because at that moment the keyboard is simply not powered up by the tablet.

In the end my questions are - **Are there maybe any crucial kernel configs that I've omitted when compiling the kernel? Can be the not working keyboard really a kernel issue? Are there any debug techniques in case I have only one micro USB port?**